# Is it possible to cross-link JavaScript from parent site?

Tags: javascript, subdomain

I want to know if it would be possible to link the JavaScript from my main site "http://example.com" to my subdomain "http://subsite.example.com".

They are not hosted on the same server.

I'm thinking that for security reasons, JavaScript cannot be cross-linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way to do it:
http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/

Never tried it myself, but had it in favs for a while waiting to need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean if it is possible for you to retrieve a javascript file that is hosted at a seperate location from this page that you have, yes. In fact Google CDN allows you to link popular libraries such as jQuery so as to offload this from your server, and also possibly faster. So its perfectly fine for your situation.